# How to use ListPlot with specific form of data

Tags: plotting

I have a big data in this form `{x,{y1,y2}}`

```
expData = {{5.6, {4.5, 7.5}}, {7, {1.5, 7.5}}, {20, {2,12}}, {31, {1.5, 10}}};
```

I am trying to use `ListPlot` as `ListPlot[expData]` but did not work?
I can manipulate the data form to be in the standard form of MMA using `Table`, but is there a direct or short way to make MMA plot this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several alternative ways:

```
lpdata1 = Thread[Thread /@ expData];

lpdata2 = Transpose@ReplaceAll[{a_, {b_, c_}} :> {{a, b}, {a, c}}] @ expData;

td = TemporalData[expData[[All, 2]], {expData[[All, 1]]}];
```

All give the same result when used with `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot`:

```
Row[ListLinePlot[#, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {lpdata1, lpdata2, td}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
expData = {{5.6, {4.5, 7.5}}, {7, {1.5, 7.5}}, {20, {2, 
     12}}, {31, {1.5, 10}}};
f[{x_, {y1_, y2_}}] := {x, y1};
g[{x_, {y1_, y2_}}] := {x, y2};
ListPlot[{f /@ expData, g /@ expData}]
```

Comment: `expData = {{5.6, {4.5, 7.5}}, {7, {1.5, 7.5}}, {20, {2, 
     12}}, {31, {1.5, 10}}};
ListPlot[{{#1, #2[[1]]} & @@@ expData, {#1, #2[[2]]} & @@@ expData}]`